# Symfony: Widget schema does not include the following field(s): title

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-forms

I'm working in a symfony-based project. I did not do.

The page works in a simple webserver (debian+apache+php) and i move this from my home server, with Debian + Nginx + php-fpm, this works, but it throws an error that did not.

The complete error is here: http://pastebin.com/PCy0v1J6

Comment: You can try to clear the cache : `./symfony cc`

Comment: Yes, i rebuild the model, the forms, etc and clear the cache, every times.

Answer (score 0):

Have you moved all your files? I guess that Brick is an object in your schema.yml, and it has  a property 'title'. You should have a file BaseBrickForm.class.php in lib/form/doctrine/base, if you don't you should execute ./symfony doctrine:build --all-classes. It's common to have the autogenrated classes ignored by a versioning system, so it may be the source of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/form/brickForm.class.php line 23ff you have :

```
$this->useFields(array('title', 'content'));
```

Please check the widgets defined in your BaseBrickForm.class.php file and if brickForm.class.php is extending BaseBrickForm !